# Using conditionals for a given function in Mathematica

Tags: functions, programming, conditional

I have two versions of a function (`A` and `B`)

When `A` fails, I get `False`. If this happens, I would like to execute `B`.

How can I do this in `Mathematica`?

**Edit**:
The code is to look like:

```
p = "string1";
a = A[];
(*check if `a` is not False *)
If[a==False, p="string2"; a = B[], Print["it is Ok"]]
```

This only works when `a` is `False`, but not when `a` has a result

Comment: You have lots of constructs available to you e.g `If[A[],...,B[]]` , `CheckAbort[A[], B[]]`, `Catch`/`Throw` etc. Read the documentation.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Use `If[a===False` i.e. `===` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `If[a===False` i.e. `===` instead of `==`.